# mysql IF ELSE statement syntax error

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
    SELECT 
     * 
FROM 
    `hssData` 
WHERE 
    `group` = 'LGA_737_CA' 
    AND (
        `pos` = 'CA' OR `pos` = 'RC'
    ) 
    AND (
        `depTimeInt` >= 0 AND `depTimeInt` <= 1440
    ) 
    AND (
        `arrTimeInt` >= 1050 OR `arrTimeInt` <= 45
    ) 
    AND `days` >= 1 
    AND `days` <= 2 
ORDER BY 
    `depTime` ASC 
LIMIT 
    0, 100
```

...except that when `arrTimeInt <= 45` I want :

```
`days` >= 1 AND `days` <= 1
```

And not

```
`days` >= 1 AND `days` <= 2
```

I have tried:

```
       SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    `hssData` 
WHERE 
    `group` = 'LGA_737_CA' 
    AND (
        `pos` = 'CA' OR `pos` = 'RC'
    ) 
    AND (
        `depTimeInt` >= 0 AND `depTimeInt` <= 1440
    ) 
    AND (
        `arrTimeInt` >= 1050 OR `arrTimeInt` <= 45
    ) 
    AND (
        IF (`arrTimeInt` < 45) THEN (
            `days` <= 1 AND `days` <= 3
        ) ELSE (
            `days` <= 1 AND `days` <= 2
        )
    ) 
ORDER BY 
    `depTime` ASC 
LIMIT 
    0, 100
```

but this throws a syntax error.

I am unable to get the correct syntax. what am I doing wrong?  The syntax error is:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ') THEN (
>               `days` <= 1 
>               AND `days` <= 2
>           ) ELSE (
>               `days` <= 1 
>               A' at line 20

Comment: Add the error message please

Comment: "this throws a syntax error" _What_ error?

Comment: `days >= 1 AND days <= 1` the only solution to this boolean logic is `days = 1`

Comment: @Martin True, and then the code itself actually performs the same less-or-equal comparison twice.

Comment: Try a closen paren immediately after your * AND `days` <= 1*

Comment: Your understanding of the SQL grammar is lacking. `if` and friends can't just be embedded in any part of any other expression. `if THING then (THIS and THAT) else (WHATEVER)` in a conditional is expressed as `( THING and (THIS and THAT) ) or (not THING and WHATEVER)`. Alternatively, you could use `case`, but I think that looks pretty bad: `case when THING then case when THIS and THAT then 1 else 0 end else case when WHATEVER then 1 else 0 end`

Comment: I have edited to include the error message, and also change the `days` conditional to avoid the ambiguity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to a [procedural construct](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html) in a non-procedural context.

Within a SELECT (or UPDATE or DELETE) statement you need to use the [IF function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html) (or CASE). Hence:

```
 SELECT 
   * 
 FROM 
    `hssData` 
 WHERE 
  `group` = 'LGA_737_CA' 
  AND (
    `pos` = 'CA' 
    OR `pos` = 'RC'
  ) 
  AND (   // brackets in this clause are redundant
    `depTimeInt` >= 0 
    AND `depTimeInt` <= 1440
  ) 
  AND (
    `arrTimeInt` >= 1050 
    OR `arrTimeInt` <= 45
  ) 
  AND `days` >= 1 
  AND `days` <= IF(`arrTimeInt` <= 45, 1, 2)
ORDER BY 
  `depTime` ASC 
LIMIT 
  0, 100
```